# Decodificar String

Tags: php

estou precisando decodificar uma string vinda de um equipamento externo via PHP.

Este equipamento se trata de um rastreador que emite informações em um intervalo de tempo para um determinado host e porta.
Criei um socket que lê o mesmo host e porta do rastreador e consegui receber uma mensagem.
Esta é a parte do código que estou utilizando para mostrar os valores recebidos.

```
socket_listen($webSocket);

        $buff = @socket_read(socket_accept($webSocket), 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ);
        echo "Numero de dados recebidos: $flgSl \n";

        $receiveStrHex = fread($buff);

        var_dump($receiveStrHex);
```

Parte da string recebida:
**eˆ7Xðž,ÒYšþøƒçü  À            ?   ¸0  ô'P  ’R@ hB×U    eˆ7Xðž,ÒYšþøƒçü  À**

Havia tentando utilizar o método unpack() mas também não obtive sucesso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem secreta? é problema de encondig?

Comment: Creio que não seja problema, pois outro software já realizava o procedimento de leitura deste tipo de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se tratava de nenhuma mensagem codificada.

Esta string se trata de alocamento de memória enviado pelo equipamento. Para tratar a mensagem e conseguir trabalhar com a mesma, converti a string para hexadecimal.